# How to redirect to a post action from a get action mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http

I have the following Get action:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous, OnlyAnonymous]
        public ActionResult VerifyVoucherCode()
        {
            var model = new VerifyVoucherCodeModel();

            model.VoucherCode = Request.GetFirstQueryValue("token", "voucherCode");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.VoucherCode))
            {
                 // prepopulates the code for the user already in a form 
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

And a POST action for when the user submits the form:

```
 [HttpPost, AjaxOnly]
        [AllowAnonymous, OnlyAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult VerifyVoucherCode(VerifyVoucherCode model)
        {
            return ExecuteAction(() =>
            {
                // do something 
            });
        }
```

I want to change the logic so that if the voucher code is in the request, the form is submitted automatically for the user without them having to submit the form themselves (i.e. it takes them straight to that Post action). I've  looked at lots of Stack Overflow questions and answers and it seems I cannot redirect to the Post action. I have also tried creating a second Get action which calls the Post action but that does not work either. Does anyone know the correct way to approach this problem?

Thanks

Comment: you could return a view which contains the form, and some javascript to automatically submit the form as soon as the page loads.

Comment: Or, instead of having two actions, if the Verify action can save the data directly, why involve another action method, why not just say `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.VoucherCode)) { //code to save the data goes here }`?

Comment: Thanks @ADyson - what do you mean by save the data? As I want the form to be submitted automatically if there's data

Comment: Your comment inside the VerifyVoucherCode method says "prepopulates the code for the user already in a form". So this implies you already have all the data needed for submitting the form. What does the `VerifyVoucherCode(VerifyVoucherCode model)` method actually do when the data is received? It seems to me that you could simply make the first method do the same thing, rather than trying to invoke one action method from another

Answer (score -2):

Assuming the model contains a single string for the voucher, you can do something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous, OnlyAnonymous]
public ActionResult VerifyVoucherCode(string id)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
{
    MyModel model1 = new MyModel();
    ...
    return View(model1);
}
    //otherwise process the voucher here
    ...
    return RedirectToAction("SuccessMsg");
}
```

Comment: The first part of your code is good practice - reading the `id` from the action method's parameters instead of using `Request.GetFirstQueryValue`. I agree the OP should adopt this for reading the incoming value. But...it doesn't answer the question they actually asked. They can't use `RedirectToAction` because the action they want to call accepts POST requests, and a redirect can only ever be a GET.